# E-Equivalences of E-local spectra are weak equivalences

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Let $E$ be a spectrum. Following the video linked below, we say that a spectrum $Z$ is $E$-acyclic if $E_*Z=0$ and a spectrum $X$ is $E$-local if $[Z,X]=0$ whenever $Z$ is $E$-acyclic.

According to the video, from these definitions it is possible to prove that if $X,Y$ are $E$-local, and if there is an map $f:X\to Y$ inducing isos on $E_*$, then $f$ induces isos on $\pi_*$. I messed around with this claim for a bit, but I could not see a way to make use of the locality assumption.

Video at specified time: https://youtu.be/ZsHtsx_A8j8?t=2313

Screenshot of the slide in the video:
[Lecture slide describing the above information and exercise.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFV38.png)

Answer (score 1):

Let $X \to Y$ be a $E$-equivalence of $E$-local objects.  Let $F$ be its fiber.  Since $X \to Y$ is a $E$-equivalence, $F$ is $E$-acyclic.  Then, since $X$ *and $Y$* are $E$-local, the fiber $F$ is $E$-local as well (use the five lemma).  So $F \simeq 0$.  Therefore, the map $X \to Y$ is a weak equivalence.

Comment: Is the assumption that Y is E-local used here?

Comment: Good catch.  Corrected.